# What does this new Microsoft Word icon mean?

Tags: microsoft-word

My docx icon suddenly changed from [image] to the following. What's the meaning of the icon below?

[image]

Comment: When an application is updated, it often includes an update to its icon. The same thing happened with LibreOffice icons for its suite of applications, recently.

Comment: Right-click the icon, select Properties, then Change Icon. Add a screenshot for dialog to your post.

Comment: Which version of Word are you using? Which operating system? If it changed for all .docx files, and those files open with Word, it means that MS changed the icon, either in Office, or in Windows. They do that sometimes. If files with that icon open in a different program, that is a separate problem and you should amend your question so it can be addressed.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon It didn' change all .docx files. docx file continues to open in MS Word

Comment: Difference between ones with the icon and those without? Any in compatibility mode?

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely no difference, the new icon is called "Thumbnail" & you can see a mini preview of the document without opening it.

You can activate or deactivate "Thumbnails" by going to:

File | Info | Properties | Advanced Properties | Summary | Save Thumbnails for all word Documents.
[image]

[image]
This will activate or deactivate Thumbnails for all future documents.

Comment: If you think this is the correct answer please accept it as such. Thanx